# How to write to file with redirection/pipes if it's read-only

Tags: permissions, io-redirection, chmod, readonly

So this seems to work:

```
chmod 777 config.json
node declarations.js > config.json
chmod 444 config.json
```

but that seems like extra steps. is there some way to write to a file with redirection and change the mode or something?

Note that the file is mode 444, so I have too change it to writable, and then I change it back above, but there has to be a quicker way? idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way. You could write a program and use it in the same sort of way that one uses `tee`

```
#!/bin/sh
chmod +w "$1"
cat > "$1"
chmod -w "$1"
```